# Cant Open Lua Scene Spine Test Cocos2dx v4

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-4.0

im using cocos Lua v4. and im looking how to create spine in Lua. But unfortunately, when im open Lua Test in Spine section. Its not showing spine, i got this error

> attempt to index global ‘sp’ (a nil value)
> [image: Lua Test]

[image: Lua Error]

Its that a bug ? if is not, how can i fix it so i can create spine in Lua ? Thanks

**Edit 1**
Here how to make spine in cocos lua v4

```
require "cocos.spine.SpineConstants"

function SpineTestLayerNormal:init()
  local skeletonNode = sp.SkeletonAnimation:create("spine/spineboy-ess.json", "spine/spineboy.atlas", 0.6)
end
```

in *cocos/spine/SpineConstants*

```
if nil == sp then
    return
end

sp.EventType =
{
    ANIMATION_START = 0, 
    ANIMATION_INTERRUPT = 1,
    ANIMATION_END = 2, 
    ANIMATION_COMPLETE = 3,
    ANIMATION_DISPOSE = 4,
    ANIMATION_EVENT = 5,
}
```

Comment: I am 99% sure this is a bug in your code

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer, im feel not change anything in Cocos. its strange. Do you test it ? can you make a spine with cocos Lua v4 ?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer have take a look to my post again please, i have update the code in cocos

Answer (score 0):

No.1

```
local spineSP = sp.SkeletonAnimation:createWithJsonFile("tank/tank-pro.json","tank/tank-pma.atlas")
spineSP:pos(display.width / 2, display.height / 2):addTo(self)
spineSP:setAnimation(0, "drive", true)
```

No.2

```
local spineSP = sp.SkeletonAnimation:createWithBinaryFile("tank/tank-pro.skel", "tank/tank-pma.atlas")
spineSP:pos(display.width / 2, display.height / 2):addTo(self)
spineSP:setAnimation(0, "drive", true)
```

No.3

```
-- 创建缓存，全局变量以便于不被释放
cachedData = sp.SkeletonData:create("tank/tank-pro.json", "tank/tank.atlas")
local spineSP = sp.SkeletonAnimation:createWithData(cachedData)
spineSP:pos(display.width / 2, display.height / 2):addTo(self)
spineSP:setAnimation(0, "drive", true)
-- 测试从一个 sp.SkeletonData 多次创建
self:performWithDelay(function()
    local spineSP = sp.SkeletonAnimation:createWithData(cachedData)
    spineSP:pos(display.width / 2, 100):addTo(self)
    spineSP:setAnimation(0, "drive", true)
end, 1)
```